# Avoid deadlock among data-read in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks, snapshot-isolation

We have an issue with "deadlocks" in SQL Server, where there are no explicit locks involved and would like to know, how to get around them.

Some relevant background info: Our application is quite old and large. We recently began to remove some concurrency-hindering issues and doing so we stepped onto the deadlock-thing on SQL Server. We do not have the resources to tackle each select statement within the application but are looking for a more general approach on configuration level.

We can reduce one exemplary problem as follows: Basically, we have two entities, `EntityA` and `EntityB`. Both are mapped to individual tables in the SQL Server schema. Between both entities, there is a m:n relation, mapped within the database via a `AToB` table, which contains some additional context (i.e. there can be more than one entry within `AToB` regarding the same `A` and `B`.

During one business operation a new instance of `A` and `B` are inserted into the database and also multiple entries within the `AToB` table. Within the same transaction at a later point all this data is read again (**without** `for update`). When executing this operation in parallel deadlocks occur. These deadlocks are linked to the `AToB` table.

Say, we have `A1` and `B1`, which are linked via `A1B1_1` and `A1B1_2` and `A2` and `B2`, which are linked via `A2B2_1` and `A2B2_2`.
My guess is the following happens:

```
t1 -> INSERT A1
t1 -> INSERT B1
t1 -> INSERT A1B1_1 (PAGE1)
t2 -> INSERT A2
t2 -> INSERT B2
t2 -> INSERT A2B2_1 (PAGE1)
t1 -> INSERT A1B1_2 (PAGE2)
t2 -> INSERT A2B2_2 (PAGE2)
t1 -> SELECT * FROM AToB WHERE AToB.A=A1
t1 -> SELECT * FROM AToB WHERE AToB.A=A2
```

Now, during concurrent reads on the `AToB` table `t1` obtains a lock on `PAGE1` and `t2` obtains a lock on `PAGE2` resulting in a deadlock.

First question: Is this a plausible explanation for the deadlock to occur?

Second question: During research I was given the impression, an index on `AToB.A` might force SQL Server to lock less entries on the table (possibly even reducing it to a row- instead of a page lock). Is this right?

Third question: I further got the impression, this problem might be solved by snapshot-locking. Is that right?

We tried this approach, however it lead us into the next circle of hell:
During the business-transaction at one point a business-identifier is assigned to `A`. This comes from a separate table and it must be unique among the `A`s. There is no possibility to assign this via a database-sequence. Our solution is to assign this identifier via an `select`/`update` on a fourth table `Identifier`. This is done via a `for update` statement. When employing snapshot-locking this `for update` lock is ignored during acquisition and only leads to an optimistic locking exception during commit. This leads us to

Fourth question: When using snapshot-locking, is it possible to still have a special transactions, which still run on pessimistic locking or is it possible to tell SQL Server, some tables are excluded from optimistic locking?

Comment: This might be a better fit for [dba.se] but I think it could still be closed because it is too broad (too many questions in 1) and also there are no specifics. I would ask 1 specific question per post (solves issue 1). Include an [mcve] with each question, for this I would include a sample ddl as well as some transact sql that could reproduce the issue if executed in the correct sequence. Also include the sql server version and compatibility level in your question.

Comment: Do you have indices that fully cover the `where` of the "at a later point all this data is read again"?

Comment: Adding to what Igor has already said, the deadlock topic is a very large one, and aside from a few general good database design tips (indexes etc)they are  almost impossible to debug/assist with without access to the actual system. I've debugged a lot of deadlocks over the years and they are all quite different.

Comment: So there  is no opportunity to simply use an `IDENTITY` in  `A` to generate the identifier? This 'special external identifier' logic always causes these kinds of issues. I always challenge these requirements although I understand that it is obviously embedded into your system and probably impossible to refactor, I'm suprised there isn't already an index on `AtoB.A`. Frequent advice around deadlocks is to make everything complete as quickly as possible, i.e. indexes